# Flask does not display JPG image

Tags: python, flask

I created a simple flask app to show results of some image analysis that is being performed on a remote server.

Another app places the image analysis result as `output.jpg` , that I would like to display by accessing and address `http://localhost:5005/image_analysis_result`

Just refer to the function `get_image_analysis_result()`:

**Here is the simple Flask app:**

```
from flask import Flask, json, request 
import requests  
import socket
from datetime import date, datetime
from requests.models import Response
import os

JADE_REMOTE_IP = "10.1.0.8"
JADE_REMOTE_PORT = "7778"
IMAGE_RESULT_PATH = "/root/nana/nana/jade/jade/nana_edge_ai/nana_edge_ai/static/outputs/output.jpg"

def returnPublicIP():
    h_name = socket.gethostname()
    IP_address = socket.gethostbyname(h_name)
    return IP_address


#TODO: the URLs in services JSON need to be auto  generated to append UE capabilities
services =[{"id": 1,"type": "image_analysis","url": "http://"+returnPublicIP()+":5000/image_analysis"}]

#TODO: the URLs in services JSON need to be auto  generated to append gNodeB capabilities
image_result = [{"result_url":"http://"+JADE_REMOTE_IP+":"+JADE_REMOTE_PORT+"/acc"}]


class MockResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self,url='http://example.com', headers={'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=UTF-8'},status_code=200,reason = 'Success', _content = 'Some html goes here',json_ = None,encoding='UTF-8'):
        self.url = url
        self.headers = headers
        if json_ and headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
            self._content = json.dumps(json_).encode(encoding)
        else:
            self._content = _content.encode(encoding)

        self.status_code = status_code
        self.reason = reason
        self.encoding = encoding

api = Flask(__name__)

def get_raw_request(request):
    request = request.prepare() if isinstance(request, requests.Request) else request
    headers = '\r\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in request.headers.items())
    body = '' if request.body is None else request.body.decode() if isinstance(request.body, bytes) else request.body
    return f'{request.method} {request.path_url} HTTP/1.1\r\n{headers}\r\n\r\n{body}'

@api.route('/services', methods=['GET'])
def get_services():
    return json.dumps(services)

#References: requests API : https://realpython.com/python-requests/
#References: #https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp
@api.route('/image_analysis', methods=['POST'])
def get_image_analysis():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Test'}
    #NEED TO SETUP WSIG JADE ADD-ON response = requests.get("http://"+JADE_REMOTE_IP+":"+JADE_REMOTE_PORT+"/acc")
    print(response.text)
    return response

#JUST LOOK AT THIS FUNCTION
@api.route('/image_analysis_result', methods=['GET'])
def get_image_analysis_result():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Test'}
    #1) result path 
    path = IMAGE_RESULT_PATH
    # Check whether the specified path exists or not
    isExist = os.path.exists(path)
    if (isExist==True):
        content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>sent message</h1><p><image width='100%' height='100%' src='{{url_for('static',filename = 'outputs/output.jpg')}}' ></p></body></html>"
    else:
        content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>sent message</h1><p>NO RESULT</p></body></html>"

    mock_response = MockResponse(
    headers={'Content-Type' :'application/html'},
    status_code=200,
    json_=json,
    reason='Success',
    _content=content)

    return mock_response.content


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5005, debug=True)
```

The result is a broken img tag?

[image]

**And Flask server log shows:**

```
 * Detected change in '/root/nana/nana/jade/jade/nana_edge_ai/nana_edge_ai/nanaTestFlaskApi.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 195-909-187
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2021 17:32:03] "GET /image_analysis_result HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2021 17:32:04] "GET /%7B%7Burl_for( HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

How can I fix the image output?

Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem right here: You did not define a path for `/%7B%7Burl_for(`, did you?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2021 17:32:04] "GET /%7B%7Burl_for( HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I don't know what `MockResponse` is supposed to do with the template `{{url_for('static',filename = 'outputs/output.jpg')}}'`, but clearly is not being expanded.

Comment: He is not suposed to "define" a path called `/%7B%7Burl_for(`. `/%7B%7Burl_for(` is just flask syntax for templates.

Comment: @Fredericka, I know. But the template syntax (in the path!) is not interpreted, it stays unchanged and shows up that way in the server log.

Answer (score 0):

First, all images, css and JavaScript files should be in a "static folder" that is in the same folder as your nanaTestFlaskApi.py. Also, the syntax "{{}}" that you are using is suposed to be written in a html file and is processend by flask.rendertemplate(). I won't use it in this example to keep things simple.
So with that in mind, the new path sould be something like `path = "static/image.jpg"` Then you place your path in the content using a formated string

```
content = f"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>sent message</h1><p><image width='100%' height='100%' src='{path}' ></p></body></html>"
```

Now you just have to implement this into your class MockResponse:

```
resp = make_response(content)
return resp
```

Also, i am not sure why you are using a custom class. The two class (makeresponse & render_template) provided by flask are well fitted for almost everything.